# addchild in a movieclip in a movieclip in a movieclip

Tags: actionscript-3, this, movieclip, addchild

I would addchild to a movieclip who is in a movieclip who is in another movieclip.

I try:

```
this.profil.bonome0.bonome.addChild(conteneurImage);
```

and it doesn't work but this does:

```
this.profil.bonome0.addChild(conteneurImage);
```

how could I access to the third movieclip (bonome)?

Comment: What do you mean by doesn't work? Try to `trace(this.profil.bonome0.bonome)`, is this MC even on stage at that time? Check if you have it placed on **THE FIRST** frame and named **bonome**.

Comment: the image I want to add, is only added to the second motionclip, and not the third, my AS3 format knowledge is very bad. I think I forget some () but don't know where

Comment: Check what I wrote in the first comment.

Comment: OK my second movieclip was bad construct, sorry :D

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is perfectly fine and your code should work, assuming the following:

1. A MovieClip named `profil` exists in the current context.
2. A MovieClip named `bonome0` exists within `profil`.
3. A MovieClip named `bonome` exists within `bonome0`.

Point 3 is where you seem to be having trouble, so check to be sure that you have a MovieClip nested inside `bonome0` with the instance name `bonome`.

To debug, you can trace each of the MovieClips until you hit `undefined`, which will mean you *don't* have a MovieClip nested with the instance name you're trying to access it by. e.g.

```
trace(
    profil,
    profil.bonome0,
    profil.bonome0.bonome
);
```